# Vmware vSphere Web Services API: retrievePropertiesEx causes stack overflow error on IIS/IIS Express, but works fine in console application

Tags: iis, vmware, iis-express, vsphere, esxi

I'm creating an interface to ESXi using the vSphere web services API. This is using VB.Net. retrieveProperties and  retrievePropertiesEx are API functions that are used to gather property data for dynamic properties within the ESXi.

My calls to retrieveProperties and retrievePropertiesEx work fine in a console test application, but throw a stack overflow error only when running that function on IIS or IIS express. This also only happens on requests to retrieveProperties that return large data sets (particularly a call to retrieve a VM configuration for example)

Any idea on what would be different between an IIS environment and just running from a standard console application? I've tried running IIS express in 64bit mode as well and same results. If this were a memory issue I would expect an out of memory exception and not a stack overflow.

the web project (ASP.Net MVC) references a common library I've built in VB.Net that runs these vsphere API calls. The same library referenced in a basic console application does not throw the same stack overflow exception when debugging or running a release copy.

**Update:** This seemed to only be an issue with the vSphere Web Services SDK Version 6.5. When re-compiling the vim25service.dll using SDK version 7.0 source it resolved the stack overflow within IIS on retrievePropertiesEx.

Comment: First, please check if there are any error messages related to Stackoverflow exception in the Event Viewer, or you can also install the [Windows Debug Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugger-download-tools) Debug Diag to get the  details information.

Comment: Fixed by using the latest vSphere Web Services SDK libraries (v 7.0 U2)